# Proving $f^{*}(\cup\mathscr{B})=\bigcup (f^*)_*(\mathscr{B})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

**Note**: $f^*$ denotes the **preimage**, while $f_*$ denotes the **image**

I have a question about proving the above statement. Let $\mathscr{B}\subset \mathscr{P}(Y)$, where $\mathscr{B}$ is a family of subsets of $Y$, and $\mathscr{P}$ denotes the power set. The question asks to show that the preimage of the union of the family is equivalent to the union of the image of the preimage of the family $\mathscr{B}$. That is, that
$$f^*\left(\bigcup\mathscr{B} \right)=\bigcup (f^*)_*(\mathscr{B}) $$ So far, my approach is as follows:

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function. Then the preimage of $\mathscr{B}$ is given by
$$f^*(\mathscr{B})=\{x\in X|\exists_{y\in\mathscr{B}}f(x)=y \} $$
That is, a mapping of $f^*: \mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}(Y)\longrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$. The image of the preimage is then equivalent to $(f^*)_*(\mathscr{B})=f_*(f^*(\mathscr{B}))=f_*\{x\in X|\exists_{y\in\mathscr{B}}f(x)=y \}=\{y\in Y|\exists_{x\in f^*(\mathscr{B})}f(x)=y \}$. This is then a mapping $\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}X\longrightarrow\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}Y$. The union of this is where I get stuck. I think it is
$$\bigcup (f^*)_*(\mathscr{B})=\{y\in Y|\exists_{B\in\cup\mathscr{B}} y\in B \} $$
which defines a canonical mapping $\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}(Y)\longrightarrow \mathscr{P}(Y)$ rather than the desired $\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}(Y)\longrightarrow\mathscr{P}(X)$ such that it is equivalent to $f^*\left(\bigcup \mathscr{B} \right)=\{x\in X|\exists_{y\in\cup\mathscr{B}} f(x)=y \}$, whcich is a map from $\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}(Y)\longrightarrow\mathscr{P}(X)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of $\mathscr{B}$ under the mapping $f^* \colon \mathscr{P}(Y) \to \mathscr{P}(X)$ is
$$
(f^*)_*(\mathscr{B}) = \{f^*(B) : B \in \mathscr{B}\}.
$$
So, another way to write the equality
$$
\textstyle
f^* \left( \bigcup \mathscr{B} \right) = \bigcup (f^*)_*(\mathscr{B})
$$
is as follows:
$$
\textstyle 
f^* \left( \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} B \right) = \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} f^*(B).
$$
This is really easy to prove:
\begin{align*}
\textstyle x \in f^* \left( \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} B \right) 
&\iff \textstyle f(x) \in \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} B \\[1mm]
&\iff f(x) \in B_0 \text{ for some } B_0 \in \mathscr{B} \\[1mm]
&\iff x \in f^*(B_0) \text{ for some } B_0 \in \mathscr{B} \\[1mm]
&\iff \textstyle x \in \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} f^*(B).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. This is about the line of reasoning I ended up following. I guess the confusion arose because the way preimage and image defined in my class slightly different than standard, and this made arise confusion.